# How can I make my app available as the default browser in iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, uti

If I disable Safari in the Restriction settings on iOS and I have iCab Mobile downloaded then all links will open in iCab. How do I register my app to handle links when Safari is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new URL Type with `http` as the URL Scheme and role as viewer. Go to your target > Info tab > URL Types > +